# How to disable jquery ajax- auto complete if there is no result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
   jQuery("#" + msgSubject).autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           jQuery.ajax({
               url: inboxControl.systemParams.allTemplateData + '/' + request.term + inboxControl.systemParams.API_EXTENSION,
               dataType: "json",
               async: false,
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

               error: function (jq, status, message) {
                   //alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message); 
               },
               success: function (data) {

                   if (data.results) {
                       response(data.results.templates);
                   } else {

                       response("");
                   }

               }
           });
       },
       minLength: 1

   });
```

Here is my code ,I want disable the ajax call if there no result for the text entered ,in this case i want to search a word "India",if i type "I" it will make an ajax call and search for the word with "I",suppose that the  result is null, but if i type "n" as second letter again it will make ajax call with "In",I want to stop that second ajax call if there is no response for the first request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a flag and then conditionally make the ajax request based upon the value of said flag:

```
var has_match = true;
jQuery("#" + msgSubject).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {          
        if(has_match) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: inboxControl.systemParams.allTemplateData + '/' + request.term + inboxControl.systemParams.API_EXTENSION,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                error: function (jq, status, message) {
                    //alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message); 
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.results) {
                        response(data.results.templates);
                    } else {
                        has_match = false;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    },
    minLength: 1

});
```

Comment: Now i found one new issue in this,suppose that i entered a word "INDIE" instead of "INDIA", it will return null and it wont call the ajax request again ,but if i remove the letter "E" from the "INDIE" ,Like "INDI" it wont give the result,Becaus the "has_match" have the value false,How can i solve this issue any idea..? :(

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.msgSubjectClick = function () {
        jQuery("." + preparams.displaySettings.msgSubjectClass).click(function () {

            var msgSubject = jQuery(this).attr('id');   

            if(msgSubject=="patientSubject")
            {
                var subjectID=preParams.displaySettings.patientSubjectId;
            }else
            {
               var ret = msgSubject.split("_");
               var str1 = ret[0];
               var str2 = ret[1];
               var subjectID=preParams.displaySettings.subjectID+str2;
             }

            var has_match = true;
            inboxControl.has_match=has_match;
            jQuery("#" + msgSubject).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                 if(inboxControl.has_match) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: inboxControl.systemParams.allTemplateData + '/' + request.term + inboxControl.systemParams.API_EXTENSION,
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader(preParams.API_KEY, connSysParams.apiSecretKey);
                        },
                        error: function (jq, status, message) {
                            //alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message); 
                        },
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.results) {
                                response(data.results.templates);
                            } else {

                                inboxControl.has_match = false;                             
                                jQuery("#" +subjectID).val(""); 
                                response("");
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    }
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function( event, ui )   {   

                jQuery("#" +subjectID).val(ui.item.id); 
            },


            });


        }).keypress(function(event) {

         var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

            if(keycode == '8') {

                    inboxControl.has_match = true;
             }

         });
    };
```

haii..i have fixed this issue with key code in jquery,if we press back space it will reset the value of has_match... Thanks ...